# In the iOS app implemented using MarketingCloudSDK, When the app is in the background, there is an event that the app ends after a while

Tags: sdk

In an iOS app that implements push notifications and inbox messages using MarketingCloudSDK,
When the app is in the background, the app ends after a while,
There is an issue that the application will be restarted when it is brought to the foreground again.
As a result of investigation, the following logs were confirmed in Xcode when the app was in the background.

"Background task still not ended after expiration handlers were called: <*UIBackgroundTaskInfo: 0x6000011db380>:
taskID = 35, taskName = MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence, creationTime = 5431 (elapsed = 25). This app will likely be terminated by the system. Call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(*:) to avoid this."

While in the background, it seems to send read receipts, etc.
If you execute "UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:)" as shown in the log, will they be processed normally?

If the process is not performed normally by intentionally ending the background process,
Is there any other way to avoid closing the app?